# Управление версионностью скриптов

Tags: powershell, контроль-версий

Коллеги, добрый день!
Понимаю, что вопрос скорее всего избитый и много раз обсосанный, но я всё же попытаюсь.
Исходные данные:

- есть библиотека скриптов на сервере
- есть пул скриптов, расположенных на машинах пользователей
- доставка скриптов к пользователям осуществляется путём проверки наличия файла у пользователя (этот способ не хотелось бы менять, так как каждый раз перезаписывать не есть хорошо)

теперь вопрос
если выходит новая версия скрипта, который хранится у пользователя, то как его корректно обновить?
временно отключать проверку на наличие не есть хорошо
следовательно, нужна некая система подписывания версии
кто как решает такие задачи?

Comment: Кто инициирует доставку? Клиент или сервер?

Comment: клиент при старте машины

Comment: Я бы положил рядом со скриптом `script.ps` файл `script.verson` в который бы писал текущую версию этого скрипта. А при проверке сравнивал бы локальный `script.verson` с удаленным

Comment: Ну как вариант проверять можно по md5, если не совпадают, то перезаписывать.